# zeros_Padding result different output

Tags: c#, qt, qt5, crypto++

Why it does get wrong results?
It not pkcs7 supported by the crypto ++?
I would like to know the value of the result to be like what to do.
Iv value is equal to the supposed well-delivered.

```
// c# code
private byte[] _iv;
private readonly string key = "7794b12op901252bfcea66d6f0521212";
public string decrypt(string Input)
{
    string str = "";
    RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged();
    managed.KeySize = 128;
    managed.BlockSize = 128;
    managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    managed.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    managed.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.key);
    managed.IV = this._iv;
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] bytes = null;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(Input);
                stream2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return str;
}
public string encrypt(string Input)
{
    RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged();
    managed.KeySize = 128;
    managed.BlockSize = 128;
    managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    managed.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    managed.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.key);
    managed.GenerateIV();
    this._iv = managed.IV;
    ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateEncryptor(managed.Key, managed.IV);
    byte[] inArray = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
            stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        inArray = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

Below is qt5 code.
Omit details.

QT code

```
    QString aeskey = "7794b12op901252bfcea66d6f0521212";
    QString _iv;
void Cipher::GenerateIV()
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    byte iv3[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    rnd.GenerateBlock(iv3, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    QByteArray out((char*)iv3, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    _iv = out.toBase64();
}
QString Cipher::AESencrypt(QString Qstr_in)
{
    string str_in = Qstr_in.toStdString();
    string key = aeskey.toStdString();
    GenerateIV();
    string iv = _iv.toStdString();
    string str_out;
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption encryption;
    encryption.SetKeyWithIV((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
    StringSource encryptor(str_in, true,
                 new StreamTransformationFilter(encryption,
                 new Base64Encoder(
                 new StringSink(str_out)
//                ,StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING
                ,StreamTransformationFilter::ZEROS_PADDING
           )
        )
    );

    return QString::fromStdString(str_out);
}
QString Cipher::AESdecrypt(QString Qstr_in)
{
    string str_in = Qstr_in.toStdString();
    string key = aeskey.toStdString();
    string iv = _iv.toStdString();
    string str_out;
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption decryption;
    decryption.SetKeyWithIV((byte*)key.c_str(), key.length(), (byte*)iv.c_str());
    StringSource decryptor(str_in, true,
                 new Base64Decoder(
                 new StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                 new StringSink(str_out)
//                ,StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING
                ,StreamTransformationFilter::DEFAULT_PADDING
            )
        )
    );
    return QString::fromStdString(str_out);
}
```

Comment: I don't think its Zero's padding that's causing the problems....

Comment: @Brian, were you able to determine the problem? If so, would you mind adding an answer and accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand really what your question is and I can't really comment so here what I think:

```
ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateEncryptor(managed.Key, managed.IV);
ICryptoTransform transform = managed.CreateDecryptor();
```

Both need key and IV, or at least need to be the same....

Then you used once Rijndael then AES. You could use AES in you C# too.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things jump out... In C# code, you do this:

```
private readonly string key = "7794b12op901252bfcea66d6f0521212";
...
managed.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.key);
```

In Crypto++ code, you do this:

```
QString aeskey = "7794b12op901252bfcea66d6f0521212";
...
string key = aeskey.toStdString();
```

You need to [HexDecode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder) the string in Crypto++.

---

Also, `GenerateIV` Base64 encodes on the Qt side of things:

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
byte iv3[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
rnd.GenerateBlock(iv3, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
QByteArray out((char*)iv3, AES::BLOCKSIZE);
_iv = out.toBase64();
```

But C# uses a `byte[]` (presumably *not* Base64 encoded):

```
private byte[] _iv;
```

Comment: Probably need to decode the hex in C# also, since the functionality is the same - getting ASCII values of the string, not converting hex string to bytes (in this case UTF8 gives the same as ASCII for this input data)